# How can I detect space that is not quoted or double quoted

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to create a Java regex that will replace all occurrences of white space in a string with a single space, except if that white space occurs between quotes (single or double)

If I were just looking for double quotes, I could use a look ahead:

```
text.replaceAll("\\s+ (?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", " ");
```

And if I were just looking for single quotes, I could use a similar pattern.

The trick is finding both.

I had the great idea to run the double quote pattern followed by the single quote pattern, but of course that ended up replacing all spaces regardless of quotes.

So here are some tests and expected results

```
a   b   c    d   e   -->  a b c d e
a   b   "c    d"   e -->  a b "c    d" e
a   b   'c    d'   e -->  a b 'c    d' e
a   b   "c    d'   e -->  a b "c d' e    (Can't mix and match quotes)
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in Java regex?

Assume invalid input was already verified separately. So none of the following will ever occur:

```
a "b c ' d
a 'b " c' d
a 'b c d
```

Comment: This is a common problem you're not going to be able to look ahead to solve. Its only solution is you have to match the quotes sections to go past them.

Comment: What about `"   '   '  "   "   '  "  "  '`? Which to replace and which not? I don't think that a regex can do this; this seems not to be a regular language.

Comment: @tobias_k It really doesn't need to be that robust, but in your example the double quotes are not balanced. I am assuming there will be no nesting and quotes will be balanced

Comment: "*I am assuming there will be no nesting and quotes will be balanced*" that is not what you show in last example `a   b   "c    d'   e` where `"` and `'` have no pairs.

Comment: @Pshemo I was showing that to illustrate that mixed quotes are ignored, not counted as quotes at all. If I can get the first 3 cases that would be great

Comment: I don't think a single regular expression can handle this. This would be a problem with any other regex package and programming language, not just java.

Comment: So can input contain unbalanced/nested quotes or not? Some solutions may be simply based on fact that they will detect that they are inside not closed `"` in which case they will ignore such spaces. This approach is correct if we are sure that input will never contain *wrong* data (in this case unbalanced/nested quotes). So should solution assume only correct data, or should it be also able to handle incorrect ones (this may increas difficulty of solution)

Comment: Also what about escaping? Can your input contain some escaped quotes like `a "b \"c d" e`?

Comment: I added some excluded cases to the original question

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT - Note - this answer has a fault / flaw

It requires there to be a single space between a end quote (`"` or `'`) and the characters following it to correctly match quoted strings. So `" "some-text` won't be correctly handled by this answer.

It might have more faults - but that's one.

## EDIT - Alternative Answer

I've added [another more well optimised answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34377610/406712) which doesn't have the fault.

Leaving this one here for posterity.

### Supports

This one supports escaping quotes via `\"` and `\'` and multi-line quotes.

### Regular Expression

```
([^\s"'\\]+)*("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')*(\s+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wT6tU2/1

### Replacement

`$1$2` (yes there is a space at the end)

### Visualisation

[image]

### Code

```
try {
    String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("([^\\s\"'\\\\]+)*(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*')*(\\s+)", "$1$2 ");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the replacement text (unescaped $ signs?)
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Non-existent backreference used the replacement text
}
```

### Human Readable

```
// ([^\s"'\\]+)*("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')*(\s+)
// 
// Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Default line breaks; Regex syntax only
// 
// Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^\s"'\\]+)*»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//       You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «*»
//       Or, if you don’t want to capture anything, replace the capturing group with a non-capturing group to make your regex more efficient.
//    Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^\s"'\\]+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//       A “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\s»
//       A single character from the list “"'” «"'»
//       The backslash character «\\»
// Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')*»
//    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//       You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «*»
//       Or, if you don’t want to capture anything, replace the capturing group with a non-capturing group to make your regex more efficient.
//    Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"»
//       Match the character “"” literally «"»
//       Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^"\\]*»
//          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//          The literal character “"” «"»
//          The backslash character «\\»
//       Match the regular expression below «(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*»
//          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//          Match the backslash character «\\»
//          Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) «.»
//          Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^"\\]*»
//             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//             The literal character “"” «"»
//             The backslash character «\\»
//       Match the character “"” literally «"»
//    Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'»
//       Match the character “'” literally «'»
//       Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^'\\]*»
//          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//          The literal character “'” «'»
//          The backslash character «\\»
//       Match the regular expression below «(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*»
//          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//          Match the backslash character «\\»
//          Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) «.»
//          Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^'\\]*»
//             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//             The literal character “'” «'»
//             The backslash character «\\»
//       Match the character “'” literally «'»
// Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(\s+)»
//    Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\s+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Comment: Just a fyi, this `([^\s"'\\]+)*` serves no purpose. Also, this regex will only match quotes when they are next to whitespace which means it will match the highlighted in here -> '`<spaces>`'asdf. Nice unrolled loop though.

Comment: Nice spot @sln I can confirm that this does require a space after the ending quote. So `"        "some-text` would not match. @sli the element `([^\s"'\\]+)*` is actually a performance element, in my quick test suite on a 40MB file resulted in halving the processing time - might have been a fluke - I wasn't paying that much attention after the first couple of iterations of the regex.

Comment: Hi Dean. Well, since everything is optional except the whitespace at the end, anything not matching those options, won't get matched. That means it' going to jump into quoted strings all the time. Then, all whitespace's between quotes that match `"  "\S` will be a target. This all assumes the quotes are balance correctly, which there is no provision for in the regex.

Comment: I've added a [2nd separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34377610/406712) as an alternative, also making an edit to make the main fault obvious with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend standardizing your string encapsulation.
the use a regex to replace the alternate to the standard.
lets say you settle on double quotes "
then you could split your string on " and all your odd elements
are quoted contents and your even elements will be unquoted,
run your regex replace on only the even elements and rebuild your string
from the altered array.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**  Since @DeanTaylor fixed his regex, I will fix (modify) this one,
in case someone decides to use it on unbalanced quotes.

The original test for balanced quotes had an atomic group.
I never added it to the parse logic. So, that was added. And that's it.

---

You can either match quotes or whitespace in an alternation and
determine which group matched to decide what to replace.

*OR* use this regex to get both, avoiding decision.

Find:  `\G((?>"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[^"'\s]+)*)\s+`

`"\\G((?>\"(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^\"\\\\])*\"|'(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^'\\\\])*'|[^\"'\\s]+)*)\\s+"`

Replace:  `$1<space>`

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 \G                            # Must match where last match left off
                               # (This will stop the match if there is a quote unbalance)
 (                             # (1 start), quotes or non-whitespace 
      (?>                           # Atomic cluster to stop backtracking if quote unbalance
           "
           (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^"\\] )*     # Double quoted text
           "
        |                              # or,
           '
           (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*     # Single quoted text
           ' 
        |                              # or,
           [^"'\s]+                      # Not quotes nor whitespace
      )*                            # End Atomic cluster, do 0 to many times
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s+                           # The whitespaces outside of quotes
```

---

Note - You can test the string for balanced quotes before using the above regex.
This will test the string, if it passes, it has balanced quotes.

`^(?>(?:"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*')|[^"']+)+$`

`"^(?>(?:\"(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^\"\\\\])*\"|'(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^'\\\\])*')|[^\"']+)+$"`

---

Updating @DeanTaylor *new answer* tests.

#### Example 1 - for the string `Word1  Word2` (two spaces in between words)

- this version takes ~27 steps
- @DeanTaylor's version takes ~29 steps

#### Example 2 - for the string `'example'  another_word` (two spaces in between words)

- this version takes ~51 steps
- @DeanTaylor's version takes ~36 steps (Presumably because of the un-rolled loop's)

#### Example 3 - for WordPress's  file

- this version takes ~315,647 steps
- @DeanTaylor's version takes 122,701 steps (Dean's version doesn't process single space)

Niether *Example 3* tests would produce a permalink on regex101.com.
The page becomes unresponsive, showing what a piece of junk it really is.

Answer (score 1):

### Supports

- escaping quotes via `\"` and `\'` and multi-line quotes.
- unmatched quotes where quotes are terminated by the end of the string.
- additional optimisations for large files

### Optimisations

Several optimisations to reduce the number of steps:

#### Example 1 - for the string `Word1  Word2` (two spaces in between words)

- [@sln's version here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34344129/406712) takes [~241 steps](https://regex101.com/r/wT6tU2/3)
- this version takes just [~29 steps](https://regex101.com/r/wT6tU2/4)

#### Example 2 - for the string `'example'  another_word` (two spaces in between words)

- [@sln's version here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34344129/406712) takes [~28,714 steps](https://regex101.com/r/wT6tU2/6)
- this version takes just [~36 steps](https://regex101.com/r/wT6tU2/7)

#### Example 3 - for WordPress's [`/wp-includes/media.php`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/6e49a963b174ad8a509c977ea571afdeca1fe298/wp-includes/media.php) file

- [@sln's version here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34344129/406712) causes [catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/wT6tU2/5) error
- this version takes just [~122,701 steps](https://regex101.com/r/wT6tU2/4)

### Regular Expression

```
\G((?:[^\s"']+| (?!\s)|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')*+)(\s+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wT6tU2/4

### Replacement

`$1` (yes there is a space at the end)

### Visualisation

[image: RegEx visualisation]

### Code

```
try {
    String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\G((?:[^\\s\"']+| (?!\\s)|\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*')*+)(\\s+)", "$1 ");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the replacement text (unescaped $ signs?)
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Non-existent backreference used the replacement text
}
```

### Human Readable

```
// \G((?:[^\s"']+| (?!\s)|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')*+)(\s+)
// 
// Options: Case sensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ don’t match at line breaks; Default line breaks; Regex syntax only
// 
// Assert position at the end of the previous match (the start of the string for the first attempt) «\G»
// Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «((?:[^\s"']+| (?!\s)|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')*+)»
//    Match the regular expression below «(?:[^\s"']+| (?!\s)|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')*+»
//       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, without giving back (possessive) «*+»
//       Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «[^\s"']+»
//          Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^\s"']+»
//             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//             A “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\s»
//             A single character from the list “"'” «"'»
//       Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) « (?!\s)»
//          Match the character “ ” literally « »
//          Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!\s)»
//             Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\s»
//       Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"»
//          Match the character “"” literally «"»
//          Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^"\\]*»
//             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//             The literal character “"” «"»
//             The backslash character «\\»
//          Match the regular expression below «(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*»
//             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//             Match the backslash character «\\»
//             Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) «.»
//             Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^"\\]*»
//                Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//                The literal character “"” «"»
//                The backslash character «\\»
//          Match the character “"” literally «"»
//       Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'»
//          Match the character “'” literally «'»
//          Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^'\\]*»
//             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//             The literal character “'” «'»
//             The backslash character «\\»
//          Match the regular expression below «(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*»
//             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//             Match the backslash character «\\»
//             Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) «.»
//             Match any single character NOT present in the list below «[^'\\]*»
//                Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
//                The literal character “'” «'»
//                The backslash character «\\»
//          Match the character “'” literally «'»
// Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\s+)»
//    Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) «\s+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```

Comment: Kudo's for fixing it Dean. I did add an atomic group, that fixed my problems and posted some new test links. Also, I purposely didn't use the un-rolled loop method just for contrast. The space optimization you've added don't tell the full story, the steps they list do not translate into quantitative time advantages. I benched the WP file using both versions. The file was duplicated to 12 MB. Doing a global find/replace took about 7 seconds for both.